# EmberFire Query equalTo 'false'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I'm using Ember 2.3, EmberData 2.3.2, and EmberFire 1.6.3

In my Ember route I'm returning a firebase query that looks like this:

```
  model() {
    return this.store.query('todo', {
      orderBy: 'complete',
      equalTo: false
    });
  },
```

my model looks like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  complete: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

When I query EmberFire with an equalTo: true I get back the expected results returning only items that are completed. If I query with an equalTo: false, it gives me all the records.

Is there a more appropriate way to fetch all the records where complete === false?

Comment: I emailed the [Firebase + Ember] google group and they let me know this is a bug: 
"Looks like you found a bug!

We are not correctly detecting when you pass `false`.

https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/5858d4ce9f533d5faa1f86f53a1271d1be077b59/addon/adapters/firebase.js#L315-L317

I will get this sorted ASAP."